# Interest rate model and premia with economical thinking

Tags: interest-rates

I heard the background about interest rate models from my coworker.

Especially it gives intuition to me that affine short rate model means it estimate long term interest rate by linearly add premia from estimated term structure.

And the difference of affine and market model is the market model related to market segmentation. That is it give term premia seperately each maturity section.

I really am interested in those economical background of it, but I'm short of mathematical thinking. So I need help from any reference related to them.

To organize my question What is the **economical** basis(logic) that those interest rate models?
Is there any reference, please give some hint.

And Is there any text that deals with difference above explanation(Affine short rate term premia and market model)?

Comment: An author who has written overviews of affine models research is Monika Piazzesi.